# "anazon.ca" download pending

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, chrome-for-android, downloading

My phone frequently shows a Chrome notification for "anazon.ca" with "Download pending ...". This appears frequently with a current time-stamp, even when WiFi and data is turned off.

I tried rebooting my phone, to no avail; pressing and holding on the notification just takes me to generic Chrome settings; clicking on it takes me to the download list, which doesn't show anything from anazon.ca.

I spent some time querying for "anazon.ca" and didn't find anything.

I have never browsed to Amazon on that phone.

What exactly is this (virus? trojan? harmless?) and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to community

I would suggest to clear data of download manager or chrome or both

I have faced such situation few times in past

But make sure you first backup Chrome settings and also try clearing first download managers data and if it doesn't work then clear chrome so that if only after clearing download manager's data your problem is solved you will have chrome settings as it is